# Trying to figure out why clock is not resetting and top popped balloons not displaying in game

Tags: javascript, html

This game is designed to inflate a balloon until it pops. The timer is supposed to countdown until it reaches zero. Once it reaches zero it is supposed to display under "top popped" the high score of how many balloons popped. What is happening is time keeps decrementing into negative numbers instead of stopping at zero. Also, nothing displaying under top popped.

I am receiving the following messages in the console log which I don't now how to interpret or deconstruct. I am very new to javascript.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPoXO.jpg)

Here is the JS and HTML:

```js
let startButton = document.getElementById('start-button')
let inflateButton = document.getElementById('inflate-button')

// we care about this data
let clickCount = 0
let height = 120
let width = 100
let inflationRate = 20
let maxsize = 300
let highestPopCount = 0
let currentPopCount = 0
let gameLength = 5000
let ClockId = 0
let timeRemaining = 0


function startGame() {

startButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
inflateButton.removeAttribute ("disabled")
startClock()

setTimeout(stopGame, gameLength)
}

function startClock(){
  timeRemaining = gameLength
  drawClock()
ClockId = setInterval(drawClock, 1000)
}

function stopClock(ClockId){
  clearInterval(ClockId)
}

function drawClock(){
let countdownElem = document.getElementById("countdown")
countdownElem.innerText = (timeRemaining / 1000).toString()
timeRemaining -= 1000
}

function inflate(){
  clickCount ++

height += inflationRate
width += inflationRate

if(height >= maxsize){
  console.log("pop the balloon")
  currentPopCount ++
  height = 0
  width = 0
} 
draw()
}

function draw(){
let balloonElement = document.getElementById("balloon")
let clickCountElem = document.getElementById("click-count")
let popCountElem = document.getElementById('pop-count')
let highPopCountElem = document.getElementById('high-pop-count')

balloonElement.style.height = height + "px"
balloonElement.style.width = width + "px"

clickCountElem.innerText = clickCount.toString()
popCountElem.innerText = currentPopCount.toString()
highPopCount,innerText = highestPopCount.toString()
}

function stopGame(){
  console.log ("the game is over")
  
  inflateButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
  startButton.removeAttribute ("disabled")
  
  clickCount = 0
  height = 120
  width = 100

  if(highestPopCount > currentPopCount){

  }

    currentPopCount = 0

  stopClock()
  draw()
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: wheat;
}
.balloon {
  height: 128px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue
  ;
  border-radius: 50%
  ;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Balloon Pop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div>

  <button id="start-button" onclick="startGame()" >START GAME</button>

</div>

 <button id="inflate-button" onclick="inflate()" disabled="true">Inflate <span id="click-count"> </span></button> 

 <div>
 <span>Balloons Popped:</span>
 <span id="pop-count"></span>
 </div>
 <div>
  <span>Top Popped:</span>
  <span id="high-pop-count"></span>
  </div>
 <div>
  <span>Time Remaining:</span>
  <span id="countdown">0</span>
  </div>
 <div id="balloon" class="balloon" ></div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `highPopCount,innerText` think that should not be a comma

Comment: Yeah, I fixed that one, still not working. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, another thing I have spotted is possibly the mismatching of names, `let highPopCountElem = document.getElementById('high-pop-count')` but the variable is later referenced in the draw function as `highPopCount`

Answer (score 1):

### Fix the scoping of the ClockId variable.

In your `stopClock` function, you're asking for an argument of `ClockId` but you're never passing it along, instead you're expecting the global `ClockId` to be used. The more specific scoped variable (the argument) takes over that variable name.

```
function stopClock(ClockId){
  clearInterval(ClockId)
}

/// Should be - 
function stopClock() {
  clearInterval(ClockId)
}

/// Note, I don't like using globals like you have here, but I get the low discipline on learning projects.
```

I also added the code needed to assign the highest pop count.

```
  if (highestPopCount < currentPopCount) {
    highestPopCount = currentPopCount;
  }
```

```js
let startButton = document.getElementById('start-button')
let inflateButton = document.getElementById('inflate-button')

// we care about this data
let clickCount = 0
let height = 120
let width = 100
let inflationRate = 20
let maxsize = 300
let highestPopCount = 0
let currentPopCount = 0
let gameLength = 5000
var ClockId = 0
var timeRemaining = 0


function startGame() {

  startButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
  inflateButton.removeAttribute("disabled")
  startClock()

  setTimeout(stopGame, gameLength)
}

function startClock() {
  timeRemaining = gameLength
  drawClock()
  ClockId = setInterval(drawClock, 1000)
}

function stopClock() {
  clearInterval(ClockId)
}

function drawClock() {
  let countdownElem = document.getElementById("countdown")
  countdownElem.innerText = (timeRemaining / 1000).toString()
  timeRemaining -= 1000
}

function inflate() {
  clickCount++

  height += inflationRate
  width += inflationRate

  if (height >= maxsize) {
    console.log("pop the balloon")
    currentPopCount++
    height = 0
    width = 0
  }
  draw()
}

function draw() {
  let balloonElement = document.getElementById("balloon")
  let clickCountElem = document.getElementById("click-count")
  let popCountElem = document.getElementById('pop-count')
  let highPopCountElem = document.getElementById('high-pop-count')

  balloonElement.style.height = height + "px"
  balloonElement.style.width = width + "px"

  clickCountElem.innerText = clickCount.toString()
  popCountElem.innerText = currentPopCount.toString()
  highPopCountElem.innerText = highestPopCount.toString()
}

function stopGame() {
  console.log("the game is over")

  inflateButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true")
  startButton.removeAttribute("disabled")

  clickCount = 0
  height = 120
  width = 100

  if (highestPopCount < currentPopCount) {
    highestPopCount = currentPopCount;
  }

  currentPopCount = 0

  stopClock()
  draw()
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.balloon {
  height: 128px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Balloon Pop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>

    <button id="start-button" onclick="startGame()">START GAME</button>

  </div>

  <button id="inflate-button" onclick="inflate()" disabled="true">Inflate <span id="click-count"> </span></button>

  <div>
    <span>Balloons Popped:</span>
    <span id="pop-count"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Top Popped:</span>
    <span id="high-pop-count"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Time Remaining:</span>
    <span id="countdown">0</span>
  </div>
  <div id="balloon" class="balloon"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you John, I will give that a try. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Looks to be working perfectly now. Thanks again.

Comment: @DougHughes I'm glad it worked! Upvoting, and accepting answers is a great way to say thanks on SO!